# pdfbox table header colouring not working properly

Tags: colors, pdfbox

I am usind pdfbox and trying to colour the header of the table; I had done the table drawing correctly using tutorial ' http://fahdshariff.blogspot.in/2010/10/creating-tables-with-pdfbox.html'

The code as follows

```
    //draw the rows
    float nexty = y ;
    for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
        contentStream.drawLine(margin, nexty, margin+tableWidth, nexty);
        nexty-= rowHeight;
    }

    //draw the columns
    float nextx = margin;
    for (int i = 0; i <= cols; i++) {
        contentStream.drawLine(nextx, y, nextx, y-tableHeight);
        nextx += (colWidths != null) ? colWidths[i] : colWidth;
    }
```

I got the code for colouring as follows:

```
contentStream.setNonStrokingColor( Color.RED );
contentStream.fillRect( 10, 10, 100, 100 );
```

I tried to put it but its not working as needed. I need to colour table header only. How can I achieve that. Please help me.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with "but its not working as needed"?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I got the solution, I filled the header with image, so the problem got solved, ty for your help friend